# How to rename a package after exporting it from vcpkg to nuget?

Tags: visual-c++, nuget, nuget-package, dev-c++, vcpkg

I have exported a package from vcpkg to nuget using this command: vcpkg export wtl —nuget

I now wanted to rename this vcpkg-export-*-*.1.0.nuget file to a meaningful one. How can I do it?

A rename on windows (F2) doesn’t seem to be working as the package gets its original name back when uploaded to artifactory in Azure.